Getting store error message after changing the base url in M2
I did a database dump from production using this command
magerun2  db:dump --strip="@development" var/dec18.sql

Did an import on my DEV environment. Changed the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url . I only have one website and 2 stores. NO fancy things here.
I ran the setup:upgrade , setup:di:compile and rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ &&  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f , flush the cache etc. But i still get this error on all pages:
The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.

I don't have any configuration on the config.php , i checked my env.php file. Looks good.  The bin/magento works as expected!
Any thoughts what else should I check ?
Thank you

If you're using Apache or NGINX, ensure the base_url matches the DocumentRoot or server_name.
Apache example:
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /path/to/magento/pub
ServerName your-dev-url.com
</VirtualHost>

NGINX example:
server {
listen 80;
server_name your-dev-url.com;
root /path/to/magento/pub;
...
}

Restart the server:
service apache2 restart
 # or
service nginx restart

Set the Default Website
Below code apply before backup your database then apply.
UPDATE store_website SET code = 'base', name = 'Main Website', 
is_default = 1 WHERE website_id = 1;
UPDATE store_group SET website_id = 1, name = 'Main Store', 
root_category_id = 2, default_store_id = 1 WHERE group_id = 1;
UPDATE store SET code = 'default', website_id = 1, group_id = 1, name = 
'Default Store View', is_active = 1 WHERE store_id = 1;

Reindex and Deploy Again
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:flush

Enable Developer Mode for Debugging
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Check the var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log for detailed error messages.
